# Adding template suggestion for twig based on page and content type

Tags: 8, theming

Actually twig only suggest templates files name like this:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--node--20.html.twig
   * html--node--%.html.twig
   * html--node.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
```

But I would have 2 kinds of template suggestion (like on my D6 website):
One based on page + content type : page--CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig
And other based on nodes + content-type : node--CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig or page--node-CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig

Actually I have a function in my .theme file like this but nothing change about suggestions:

```
function starterpf_d8_2019_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $path = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->getPathInfo();
  if ($path != '/') {
    $path = trim($path, '/');
    $arg = str_replace(["/", '-'], ['_', '_'], $path);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $arg;
  }
}
```

Code found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/214864/8753)

Thanks for help

EDIT: after exploring the output HTML, I get the page suggestions like this:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   x page--front.html.twig
   * page--node.html.twig
   * page.html.twig
-->
```

So, can I add different kind of suggestions with putting together part of your codes ? Like this:

```
function starterpf_d8_2019_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $path = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->getPathInfo();
  if ($path != '/') {
    $path = trim($path, '/');
    $arg = str_replace(["/", '-'], ['_', '_'], $path);
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $arg;
  }
  #Suggestions pour les nodes
   $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node_' . $node->bundle();
  }
  
  #Suggestions pour les types de contenus
   if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__'.$content_type;
  }
}
```

And if I only want to create a file like `node--CONTENT-TYPE.html.twig` instead of a page one ? Interesting in use of `node--CONTENT-TYPE-nid.html.twig` too.
And what would be better to use ? Knowing that I include field datas inside template to theme easily them ?
In some use cases I will need to theme depending taxonomy term, is this native with D8 ?

Comment: Explore the HTML output, there are dozens of templates and suggestions for every single URL, varying by context and content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function myModule_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    $suggestions[] = 'page__' . $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__node_' . $node->bundle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter` modifies suggestions for `page.html.twig`, if you want to change suggestions for `html.html.twig` you need to use `hook_theme_suggestion_html_alter`

```
function starterpf_d8_2019_theme_suggestions_html_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $path = \Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->getPathInfo();
  if ($path != '/') {
    $path = trim($path, '/');
    $arg = str_replace(["/", '-'], ['_', '_'], $path);
    $suggestions[] = 'html__' . $arg;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {

  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $content_type = $node->bundle();
    $suggestions[] = 'page__'.$content_type;
  }
}
```

Found [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2015-07-02/how-to-add-in-drupal-8-a-custom-suggestion-page-template)